# How is a ranged touch spell attack calculated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, touch-attacks

I know that when attacking with a melee weapon you would add your Attack Bonus to your attack roll and your Strength Modifier to the damage roll.
**How does this work when you're casting a ranged spell instead?**

I think I should add my BAB to the attack roll but then what?
Do I need to add the Dexterity Modifier like one does for ranged physical attacks?
Do I add any ability modifier to my damage roll?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are probably looking at a ray spell. [The Magic rules state](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell):

> **Ray**
>
> Some effects are rays. You aim a ray as if using a ranged weapon, though typically you make a ranged touch attack rather than a normal ranged attack. As with a ranged weapon, you can fire into the dark or at an invisible creature and hope you hit something. You don't have to see the creature you're trying to hit, as you do with a targeted spell. Intervening creatures and obstacles, however, can block your line of sight or provide cover for the creature at which you're aiming.
>
> If a ray spell has a duration, it's the duration of the effect that the ray causes, not the length of time the ray itself persists.
>
> If a ray spell deals damage, you can score a critical hit just as if it were a weapon. A ray spell threatens a critical hit on a natural roll of 20 and deals double damage on a successful critical hit.

Other ranged spells will state whether it's a ranged attack or a ranged touch attack, which determines whether you are trying to hit the enemy's normal AC or their touch AC.  In any event, it is a ranged attack and therefore the [Combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Combat-Statistics) state:

> Your attack bonus with a **ranged** weapon is:
>
> **Base attack bonus + Dexterity modifier + size modifier + range penalty**

Unless you have a special ability that says otherwise, you do not add anything to damage.  See [Damage in the Combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Damage) - it says you add Strength bonus to melee or thrown weapons, period.

Though you should add more context to your question - just in case you're *super* confused, let me clarify that you don't need to roll to hit on any spell just because it has a range.  Take [Fireball](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fireball), range Long. You don't roll to hit with it, you just place the 20' radius spread area wherever you want within that range (that you have line of effect to yadda yadda) and it affects everyone in that area.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So if it's a ranged spell that does require a roll to hit, then I would treat it as a ranged attack and add the appropriate modifiers.

Comment: @Nerevar That is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Touch attacks are resolved just like regular attacks, but they target touch AC instead.

**Whatever modifier would apply to a ranged roll will apply to a ranged touch attack (including your Dex modifier)** and the same stands true for melee attacks and melee touch attacks, with one notable exception: usually, when you cast a spell you're just trying to touch your enemy, not with your weapon but with the spell itself.
As a consequence, you don't add the modifiers you'd apply to your weapon (enhancement bonus, weapon focus feats relative to your weapon), applying those relative to spells instead. Also, you don't roll damage as if you were hitting with a weapon. Instead, you do whatever the spell tells you, which usually involves **no damage modifiers tied to your ability scores.**

When I say usually I mean there might be spells or features that let you use a touch attack instead of a regular attack with your weapon (there surely were in D&D 3.5, on which Pathfinder is based). Those would retain the usual weapon modifiers both to the attack roll and to the damage roll, since you'd just be using your physical attack (against a lower AC).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, melee touch attack spells are base attack + strength and ranged touch attacks are base attack + dex. You can also take weapon focus (melee touch) to get another +1 to melee touch attacks, weapon focus (ray) for +1 to ranged, and point blank shot to get another +1 to ranged touch (within 30 feet). So in general, yes, modifiers apply to spells that require touch attacks.

Answer (score 2):

So to be clear,

Melee weapons and melee touch spells-
BaB+str mod+size mod

Range weapons, rays, and range touch spells-
BaB+dex mod+range mod+size penalty

Area spells have no attack check.

Answer (score -2):

Excerpt from "Pathfinder Playtest", Page 196

> **SPELL ATTACKS**
>   Some spells require you to succeed at an attack roll to  affect the target. This is usually because they require you to touch your target, precisely aim a ray, or otherwise make an accurate attack. Any attack you make is part of the spell’s Somatic Casting action. Usually, such spells require a melee touch attack or a ranged touch attack. In both cases, make an attack roll and compare the result to the target’s TAC. Your proficiency modifier for a spell’s attack roll is the same as your proficiency modifier with spell rolls.  Spell attacks are unarmed, but they don’t apply any special benefits from your weapons or unarmed attacks, nor do they deal any damage outside of what’s listed in the spell. Melee touch attacks have the finesse trait (see page 182). On a successful attack, your spell affects the target, and on a failure the spell is lost unless otherwise noted. Spells with a range of “touch” always require a melee touch attack when used against an unwilling target, but not when used on a willing or unconscious target. Some spells require a normal melee attack or ranged attack instead of a touch attack. These work as described above, but they target AC instead of TAC.

Comment: This question was originally asked about 4 years ago, and was related to Pathfinder version 1. Your answer appears to be about the Pathfinder v2 playtest, so isn't really relevant, I'm afraid.